# Shadows and directional light in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a top-down game in Phaser 3 and want a flashlight effect, is there a way to cast a light in a certain direction, in a cone shape, maybe working something like this:
`this.flashlightBeam = this.lights.add.directionalLight(x, y, direction, beam width in degrees, brightness, rgb )`
I also want to have objects in the lighting pipeline block the flashlight beam and have shadows. Any suggestions for plugins or features of Light2D that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know phaser doesnt have this feature out-of-the-box, and there is no plugin. *(btw.: a good place to check for phaser plugins is here, https://phaserplugins.com/, but none is listed here)*

**That said**, you could fake shadows with sprites and calculating the angles. this should work well since, if the sprite is in darkness the shadow won't be seen, but when lit up the shadow would be seen.
It is not great, a neat work around

**Here a demo,**  I omitted the light part for clarity, but it should be straightforward.

that uses this SpriteSheet:
[image: spritesheet]

```js
// basic customObject -- here the shadwo logic should/could go
class ShadowObject extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {

    constructor (scene, x, y, lightSource){
        super(scene, x, y, 'shadow-object1');

        this.setOrigin(.5).setScale(10);
        this.lightSource = lightSource;
    }

    preUpdate(time, delta){
        super.preUpdate(time, delta);
        if(!this.lightSource){
            return;
        }

        let angle = Phaser.Math.RadToDeg(
            Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(
                this.x, 
                this.y,
                this.lightSource.x, 
                this.lightSource.y)
            );
        
        if( angle > 0 ){
            if( angle > 110){
                this.setFrame(2);
            } else if( angle > 80) {
                this.setFrame(1);
            } else {
                this.setFrame(0);
            }
        } else {
            if( angle < -110){
                this.setFrame(5);
            } else if( angle < -80) {
                this.setFrame(4);
            } else {
                this.setFrame(3);
            }
        }
    }
}

// basic customObject plugin
class ShadowObjectPlugin extends Phaser.Plugins.BasePlugin {

    constructor (pluginManager) {
        super(pluginManager);
        pluginManager.registerGameObject('shadowObject', this.createObject);
    }
    createObject (x, y, lightSource) {
        return this.displayList.add(new ShadowObject(this.scene, x, y, lightSource));
    }

}


let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 500,
    height: 180,
    pixelArt: true,
    physics: { default: 'arcade' },
    backgroundColor: '#427F4A',
    // Plugin registration
    plugins: {
        global: [
            { key: 'ShadowObjectPlugin', plugin: ShadowObjectPlugin, start: true }
        ]
    },
    scene: {
        create(){
            this.player = this.add.rectangle(50, config.height/2, 20, 20, 0xff0000)
                .setOrigin(.5);

            this.physics.add.existing(this.player);
            this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
            
            // extra event action, to workaround CORS restriction
            this.textures.once('addtexture', function () {
            this.obj1 = this.add.shadowObject(config.width/2, 40, this.player);

            this.obj2 = this.add.shadowObject(config.width/2, config.height - 40, this.player);
          }, this);

          // extra event action, to workaround CORS restriction
          this.textures.addSpriteSheet('shadow-object1', img, {frameHeight: 8, frameWidth:8 } )
        },
        update(){
            if(!this.player || !this.player.body)
                return;

            if (this.cursors.left.isDown){
                this.player.body.setVelocityX(-160);
            } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
                this.player.body.setVelocityX(160);
            } else {
                this.player.body.setVelocityX(0);
            }
        }
    },
    banner: false
};

// extra event action, to workaround CORS restriction
var imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAQCAMAAAA7+k+nAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJUExURf9eFICAgAAAAFsertMAAAADdFJOU///ANfKDUEAAAAJcEhZcwAADsIAAA7CARUoSoAAAABJSURBVChTrZBJDgAgDAKL/3+02BLX1IORC8jYNGolUQMmuvgFQAVgBgiwZKObDXhw96kAqyufegPpjo8g3rs5wTjPhN8y9T2jVOoAAnNNNFEPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';

let img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
  new Phaser.Game(config);
};
img.src = imageData;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

*(this can be optimized with more sprites/shadow-angles, and/or using the distance for calculating the shadow-frame that should be used)*

***Info:** Due to CORS restrictions with the `i.stack.imgur.com` image, the example needed some extra code.*

**Or** even more generic, create a/multiple customgameobject, based on a phaser-image and draw the shadow on depending on the angle in the `preUpdate` of the custom object.

Comment: Ok, thanks! defenitely a bummer that there's no plugins for anything like this.