# Phaser webgl shadows

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How can I implement Shadows With The phaser.js Webgl lighting system

```js
this.lights.enable();
this.lights.setAmbientColor(0x808080);
```

Heres what I'm Looking for:
[image]

How Do I implement the shadows coming off those trees in phaser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73666310/1679286), as far as I know you cannot create shadows/shadow effects out of the box with in phaser. Except you want to programm it with raycasting or so([link to an article](https://phaser.io/news/2021/05/phaser-raycaster)), but that would be alot of work judt for background feature, that mihht not be seen.

A *easy* solution could be use several background images, wirh different shadows an switch them out when needed (a possible example is in the aforementioned answer).